# GD 7.2.0 to 7.4.0 library upgrade issues

Tags: reactjs, upgrade, gooddata

We are upgrading our GoodData library to 7.4.0 (from 7.2.0) and the error we are getting in our build is:

```
 0=./node_modules/react-intl/lib/components/provider.js 59:15
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (59:15)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/src/build-optimizer/webpack-loader.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
|     return Object.assign(Object.assign({}, resolvedConfig), { formatters, formatNumber: formatNumber.bind(null, resolvedConfig, formatters.getNumberFormat), formatNumberToParts: formatNumberToParts.bind(null, resolvedConfig, formatters.getNumberFormat), formatRelativeTime: formatRelativeTime.bind(null, resolvedConfig, formatters.getRelativeTimeFormat), formatDate: formatDate.bind(null, resolvedConfig, formatters.getDateTimeFormat), formatDateToParts: formatDateToParts.bind(null, resolvedConfig, formatters.getDateTimeFormat), formatTime: formatTime.bind(null, resolvedConfig, formatters.getDateTimeFormat), formatTimeToParts: formatTimeToParts.bind(null, resolvedConfig, formatters.getDateTimeFormat), formatPlural: formatPlural.bind(null, resolvedConfig, formatters.getPluralRules), formatMessage: formatMessage.bind(null, resolvedConfig, formatters), formatHTMLMessage: formatHTMLMessage.bind(null, resolvedConfig, formatters), formatList: formatList.bind(null, resolvedConfig, formatters.getListFormat), formatDisplayName: formatDisplayName.bind(null, resolvedConfig, formatters.getDisplayNames) });
| }
> export default const IntlProvider = /*@__PURE__*/ function () {
|     class IntlProvider extends React.PureComponent {
|         constructor() {
 @ ./node_modules/react-intl/lib/index.js 7:0-76 7:0-76 7:0-76
 @ ./node_modules/@gooddata/react-components/dist/helpers/IntlStore.js
 @ ./node_modules/@gooddata/react-`enter code here`components/dist/components/filters/DateFilter/utils/Translations/DateFilterTitle.js
 @ ./node_modules/@gooddata/react-components/dist/components/filters/DateFilter/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/@gooddata/react-components/dist/index.js
 @ ./.skypagestmp/src/app/public/src/modules/gooddata-chart/gooddata-chart.component.js
 @ ./.skypagestmp/src/app/sky-pages.module.ngfactory.js
 @ ./.skypagestmp/src/app/app.module.ngfactory.js
 @ ./.skypagestmp/src/main-internal.aot.ts
 @ multi ./.skypagestmp/src/main-internal.aot.ts
```

Answer (score 0):

From the error message it seems the problem is with `react-intl`, which was upgraded from `2.4.0` in [`@gooddata/react-components@7.2.0`](https://github.com/gooddata/gooddata-react-components/blob/v7.2.0/package.json#L138) to `3.6.0` in [`@gooddata/react-components@7.4.0`](https://github.com/gooddata/gooddata-react-components/blob/v7.4.0/package.json#L143). Unfortunately, react-intl needs some [migration](https://formatjs.io/docs/react-intl/upgrade-guide-3x#esm-build) in certain scenarios when upgrading from v2 to v3.

Most probably, you will need to include the `react-intl` libraries into your build process as described in the [upgrade guide](https://formatjs.io/docs/react-intl/upgrade-guide-3x#esm-build) by adding the following config to your babel-loader (or typescript-loader) configuration:

```
include: [
  path.join(__dirname, "node_modules/react-intl"),
  path.join(__dirname, "node_modules/intl-messageformat"),
  path.join(__dirname, "node_modules/intl-messageformat-parser"),
],
```

Comment: I didn't really expect that we would have to do any sort of migration due to your upgrade of react-intl from 2.4.0 to 3.6.0.  It was not necessary to have a dependency to the react-intl library prior to the upgrade to 7.4.0.  However, I've added the react-intl library as a dependency in our library based on your comment (the error still remains), but we don't reference these loader libraries (babel-loader/typescript-loader) directly so I am not sure how the configuration should be handled.

Comment: You should not need to add the decency to react-intl, it will be included as the dependency of react-components. What I meant by my comment is that you probably need to make sure the react-intl and related files are included in the build/transpilation process (some build systems ignore node_modules by default). As for the loaders, can you please share what build process or framework are you using in your project, so that we can determine what to do next?